# Rails edit form is creating a new element on every form submission instead of updating the selected one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I've created an edit form in edit.html.erb, but it creates a new element every time I submit it. I've tried checking the routes, both relevant controller actions, validations in the model, etc. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I thought maybe I needed to put `<form action="/books/<%= @book.id %>" method="post">` at the beginning of the form, or maybe changing the method to 'patch,' but no combination of either of those solves the problem. I've also tried commenting out the validations, but that doesn't help either. There's only one model. Thank you and please let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong!

Here's what I have in the different files:

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
  root 'books#index'
end
```

book.rb:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :author, :total_pages, :dewey, :status, presence: true
end
```

books_controller.rb:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.create(book_params)

    if @book.status == 'Incomplete'
      @book.pages_read = @book.total_pages / 2
    elsif @book.status = 'Unread'
      @book.pages_read = 0
    else
      @book.pages_read = @book.total_pages
    end

    # Save by category
    # Must save as a string to maintain leading zeros
    if @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 0
      @book.category = "Computer Science, Information & General Works"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 1
      @book.category = "Philosophy & Psychology"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 2
      @book.category = "Religion"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 3
      @book.category = "Social Science"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 4
      @book.category = "Language"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 5
      @book.category = "Pure Science"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 6
      @book.category = "Applied Science"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 7
      @book.category = "Arts & Recreation"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 8
      @book.category = "Literature"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 9
      @book.category = "History & Geography"
    end

    if @book.valid?
      @book.save
      flash[:message] = "Book saved"
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @book.status == 'Incomplete'
      @book.pages_read = @book.total_pages / 2
    elsif @book.status = 'Unread'
      @book.pages_read = 0
    else
      @book.pages_read = @book.total_pages
    end

    # Save by category
    # Must save as a string to maintain leading zeros
    if @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 0
      @book.category = "Computer Science, Information & General Works"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 1
      @book.category = "Philosophy & Psychology"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 2
      @book.category = "Religion"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 3
      @book.category = "Social Science"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 4
      @book.category = "Language"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 5
      @book.category = "Pure Science"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 6
      @book.category = "Applied Science"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 7
      @book.category = "Arts & Recreation"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 8
      @book.category = "Literature"
    elsif @book.dewey.to_s.split('').map { |digit| digit.to_i }.first == 9
      @book.category = "History & Geography"
    end

    @book.update(book_params)

    if @book.update(book_params)
      flash[:message] = "Successfully updated."
      redirect_to @book
    else
      flash[:errors] = @book.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    flash[:message] = "Book deleted."
    redirect_to books_path
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :total_pages, :pages_read, :dewey, :category, :status)
  end

  def find_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<form action="/books" method="post">
  <%=hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 id="form-h2">Editing <%= @book.title %> by <%= @book.author %></h2>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="book[title]" value="<%= @book.title %>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" placeholder="Author" name="book[author]" value="<%= @book.author %>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_pages" placeholder="Number of pages" name="book[total_pages]" value="<%= @book.total_pages %>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dewey" placeholder="Dewey Decimal number" name="book[dewey]" value="<%= @book.dewey %>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="form-question">Have you finished this book?</p>
    <div id="radios">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="book[status]" value="Read" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label"for="customRadio1">Yes!</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="book[status]" value="Incomplete" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label"for="customRadio2">I'm still reading it</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio3" name="book[status]" value="Unread" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio3">I haven't started it yet</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button type="submit" id="add-button" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try with `patch` but with the url singular, nor plural: `/book/<%= @book.id %>"`

Comment: @Grzegorz if I do that, I get this error: No route matches [GET] "/book/17"

Comment: Ok, check out the development log when you use your form - it should tell you which route you're ending in

Comment: It actually says the same thing! ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/book/17"), followed by dozens of lines related to webpacker and activesupport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out myself, and I think you'd be much better of by using dedicated form helpers:

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <!-- all the rest of your fields --> 
<% end %>
```

Here's what that generates:

```html
<form class="edit_book" id="edit_book_4" action="/books/4" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="oyzBuqICn/+p8IENt1Dh02UOBzNyCxQ707JwcZdz/BnxocRL4wCzb18Q26DAoDqCFAuqWExII4K1ENGENEPWFA==">
  <input type="text" value="new" name="book[title]" id="book_title">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Book" data-disable-with="Update Book">
</form>
```

Notice the extra hidden field with the method `patch` there.

The sole `method` attribute does not understand `patch` or `put`, you can only use `get` and `post` in there (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Only with this special `_method` param set, you'd get a proper routing to the `update` method.

I'm not sure why you've decided to go the hard way and compose the html forms by your own, but if you want to continue - you'll have huge problems keeping the framework up to date. Imagine that rails team decide that this field is not `_method` but `__method` from now on. Going with "[canonical](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects-model-object-helpers)" way - you wouldn't even notice. Going your way - you'll have all your forms to update.

Answer (score 1):

To update a record you use `PATCH /books/:id`.

```
# Use form_for if your Rails version is older than 5.1
<%= form_with(model: @book) do |form|>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 id="form-h2">Editing <%= @book.title %> by <%= @book.author %></h2>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
    </div>
    # ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`form_with(model: @book)` is smart enough to set the action and method depending on if the model has been saved to the database. It also takes care of creating the authenticity token and the special `_method` input that Rails uses to [fake PUT, PATCH and DELETE requests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark).

This lets you share the form code beetween your views. Use the [form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to create inputs with data bindings.

If you're doing everything manually it really makes using a framework pointless - especially rails which is driven by convention of configuration which is what makes it so productive.

Comment: this question is tagged with rails-5, so probably `form_for` instead of `form_with`

Comment: @gregorz form_with was introduced in 5.1.